# Rotate a R plot with dynamic plot area

Tags: r, plot, r-grid, grob

I'm trying to rotate a plot to be incorporated into a shiny application.
I found how to rotate a plot. To get it right it seems you need to fiddle with the the `height` and `width` of the `viewport` making it not a solution for a dynamic environment where you don't known the `height` and `width` a priori.

My question now is how do I rotate my plot in such a way that it remains dynamic and responsive to plot area changes?

My example:

```
p <- ggplot2::qplot(1:10)

library(grid)
grid.newpage()
print(p, vp=viewport(0, 0, width = unit(0.5, "npc"), just = c('left', 'bottom')))
print(p, vp=viewport(0.5, 0, angle = 90, height = unit(0.8, "npc"), width = 0.55, just = c('left', 'top')))
```

Depending on how the plotting area is it looks good or bad:

## Vertically elongated

Observed: missing half of the rotated plot

[image]

Expected:

[image]

## Horizontally elongated

Observed: missing half of the rotated plot
[image]
Expected:
[image]

## Square like

Nicely how it should be - showing both plots:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Edited** upon the OP's cpmment.

We need to dynamically check dimensions of the graphics device every time the graph is plotted.

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
dev.size(units = "px")

print(p, vp=viewport(0, 0, 
                     width = unit(dev.size(units = "in")[1]*0.45, "inches"), 
                     height = unit(dev.size(units = "in")[2]*0.975, "inches"),
                     just = c('left', 'bottom')))
print(p, vp=viewport(0.5, 0, angle = 90, 
                     height = unit(dev.size(units = "in")[1]*0.45, "inches"), 
                     width = unit(dev.size(units = "in")[2]*0.975, "inches"), 
                     just = c('left', 'top')))
```

Note it does not affect changing of the graph whenever you strech it in your rstudio device preview window but it does change the size every time you newly plot your graph.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not solving my problem as it suffers from the same issues. Try stretching the graph it will look like `Vertically elongated` Observed, or `Horizontally elongated` Observed

Comment: @mmoisse Please see the corrected code  and comments concerning the time when the plotting is adjusted